# Azure DevOps Rest Call giving 401 status code

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, http-status-code-401

I am trying to do a Get Request for REST API Azure from Postman.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

I am trying to do the auth with my PAT (empty username and PAT as password) and I get 401 status code.

Can anyone tell me why it is not working ?
I dont have Full access token, I am using Custom access scope with ToKenAdmin and Tokens Scope added.

When I just try to access the link from browser, it works.

Comment: I am having this same issue my PAT is working for GET/POST API through Postman, and also working for GET calls with Python code however, not working for POST calls through Python code. I even tried with a PAT having full access but still getting 401.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Rest Call giving 401 status code

The 401 status code indicates a permission issue.

You should have the token with ToKen **Build** (Read)：

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried with Build (Read and Read & Execute both).

Comment: Any idea on why it gives 401 still ??

Comment: @user19011893, Try to create a new PAT with Build (Read and Read & Execute both) and check if you still have this issue? If yes, what is the Region of your organization?